# how to use enable_if with overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

```
enum class enabler{};

template<typename T> 
class X {
   template<typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value,enabler>::type = enabler()>
    void func();
    void func(int a);
    void func(std::string b);
};
```

I have this class with these 3 overloads for `func`. I need the second/third versions to be available for both class/non-class types, and the first version to be available only for class types. when I tried to use `enable_if` as above, the class instantiation for non-class types gives compile error.

Comment: SFINAE only works for *deduced* types.

Comment: can you elaborate more please?

Comment: You don't actually require to use sfinae. A `static_assert` is enough in your case. See the minimal example in my (late) answer.

Comment: @skypjack True, *if* this isn't a simplified example. In the non-simplified versions, it might affect overload resolution of the other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to work, the template argument must be deduced. In your case, `T` is already known by the time you attempt to instantiate `func`, so if the `enable_if` condition is `false`, instead of SFINAE, you get a hard error.

To fix the error, just add a template parameter whose default value is `T`, and use this new parameter in the `enable_if` check. Now deduction occurs and SFINAE can kick in for non-class types.

```
template<typename U = T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value,enabler>::type = enabler()>
void func();
```

And you don't really need a dedicated `enabler` type either, this works too

```
template<typename U = T,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value, int>::type* = nullptr>
void func();
```

Comment: the disadvantage of this approach is that you are able to run `func()` with explicit template parameters: `func<std::string>()` will cause class overload even if `T` is not a class

Comment: @AndreiR. Yes, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, you'll always be able to find some way to do it.

Comment: @Praetorian You can still use a guard parameter pack like `template<typename..., typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<U>::value, int>::type* = nullptr> void func();`. Explicit template parameters will be chewed away.

Comment: @mkmostafa I rejected the edit because I think you were trying to protect against people explicitly specifying a template argument for `func` and that edit doesn't solve the problem. Doing so would again mean there is no deduction, SFINAE wouldn't happen and you'd get a hard error when the condition is false.

Comment: @skypjack Sure, that's a bit better, but it's still surprising because the template arguments provided by the user have no effect. I think functions like the example above should be documented to warn users not to specify template arguments, and then leave them to do what they want.

Comment: actually I added that edit to my code and it worked perfectly. Thanks anyways for the original help :)

Comment: @Praetorian Fair enough. Anyway, as mentioned in my answer, in this case a `static_assert` is enough. The OP doesn't even require to use sfinae, for this isn't sfinae at all, it's - _substitution failure is always an error_ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're going for with `enabler` here, but you can't do what you're trying because the declaration for your member function must be valid since `T` is not deduced by `func`. To achieve what you want in adding an extra overload, you can use some moderately contrived inheritance.

```
struct XBaseImpl {
  // whatever you want in both versions
  void func(int a) { }
  void func(std::string b) { }
};

template <typename, bool> struct XBase;

// is_class is true, contains the extra overload you want
template <typename T>
struct XBase<T, true> : XBaseImpl {
  static_assert(std::is_class<T>{}, "");  // just to be safe
  using XBaseImpl::func;
  void func() { }  // class-only
};

// is_class is false
template <typename T>
struct XBase<T, false> : XBaseImpl { };

template<typename T>
class X : public XBase<T, std::is_class<T>{}> { };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not enabling or disabling something.
You simply want a compile time error in one specific case.
Because of that you don't require to rely on sfinae, a `static_assert` is enough.

As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<string>

template<typename T> 
class X {
public:
    void func() {
        static_assert(std::is_class<T>::value, "!");
        // do whatever you want here
    }

    void func(int a) {}
    void func(std::string b) {}
};

int main() {
    X<int> x1;
    X<std::string> x2;

    x2.func(42);
    x2.func();

    x1.func(42);
    // compilation error
    // x1.func();
}
```

---

Once a SO user said me: *this is not sfinae, this is - substitution failure is always an error - and in this case you should use a `static_assert` instead*.
He was right, as shown in the above example a `static_assert` is easier to write and to understand than sfinae and does its work as well.